# How to randomize(or shuffle) order of Radio Buttons

Tags: java, android, radio-button, radio-group

I want to randomize my radio buttons whenever I reopen my app.

For example my layout is like below:

```
RBtn1
Rbtn2
Rbtn3
Rbtn4
```

Now I want to shuffle them whenever I open that particular activity. How can I do this?

Comment: you only want to edit their name or their functionality also?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Hi, i'll try to answer your question based on what I understand about it. But next time try to put more usefull informations like your entire layout file or how do you create your view.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, `Layouts` in `resources` are immutable. That means you've to make `Views` in the dynamic or Java way.

What you can do is use the SecureRandom class (accurate than Random for picking random numbers) to pick a random number and take one RadioButton object from the RadioButton array what you will create.

**PoC**: I'm explaining first by a now written and tested code →

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     static String los1 = "taotao1";
     static String los2 = "taotao2";
     static String los3 = "taotao3";
     static String los4 = "taotao4";

     static String[] X = {los1,los2,los3,los4};

     public static void main(String []args){
             Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(X));
             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(X));
     }

     /*
     Test 1 : [taotao4, taotao3, taotao2, taotao1]
     Test 2 : [taotao2, taotao3, taotao4, taotao1]
     Test 3 : [taotao3, taotao4, taotao1, taotao2]
     Test 4 : [taotao2, taotao4, taotao1, taotao3]
     */

}
```

**Explanation**: `Collections.shuffle` shuffles objects in an Array as you will be able to see by running code.

**Conceptual Code**: I'm saying it conceptual because writing directly in Stack Answer Box without testing, Test to be done by you.

```
public class NoNotHelloWorld extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     RadioButton r1,r2,r3,r4; //please declare to avoid NullPtr and also declare their functionalities 

     LinearLayout xyz = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.xyzwhatisthis);
    //though unnesseary cast, but I did it.

    ArrayList<RadioButton>  dydx = new ArrayList<RadioButton>(); 
        dydx.add(r1); 
        dydx.add(r2); 
        dydx.add(r3); 
        dydx.add(r4); 

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));

    for(RadioButton dxdy : dydx){
        xyz.addView(dxdy)
    }

    }

}
```

I think it should work otherwise comment box is there.